# How I compare integer values larger than Int32.MaxValue in C#?

Tags: c#

The maximum value for `Int32` is 2,147,483,647. I am comparing integer values that are greater than the maximum value and it is not working. Maximum number can be 9999999999.99.

Which data type should I use to compare integer values larger than `Int32.MaxValue`?

Comment: Have you tried the `long` data type?

Comment: Just for reference so the asker knows: `long` and `int64` are the same thing, just different names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you deal with numbers larger than UInt64 (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298787/how-do-you-deal-with-numbers-larger-than-uint64-c)

Comment: @Sayse, not really a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: The OP should learn how to google things, or at least to read C# types docs

Comment: 9999999999.99 is not integral

Comment: I didn't expect downvotes for this.

Comment: @Sunny well , this already have many answers so sorry about that. SOmeone may see this a duplicate of some question.

Comment: Isn't duplicate and downvote different.

Comment: @Sunny If you don't want to have your question be downvoted then take the time to do some basic research before asking your question.  Do some web searches related to your question, look around, do some research.  When you spend literally zero time trying to solve a problem that is *extremely* easy to discover the solution for, you should expect downvotes.

Comment: @Sunny The 'hover' for the downvote arrow says, "This question does not show any research effort..."  That definitely applies to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) instead of an integer. That can handle numbers up into the 9 Quintillion range.

Also, given that your max value includes a decimal point, are you sure you don't want a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead?

Comment: The OP mentions the Maximum number can be 9999999999.99.  Notice the decimal point.  I think they should be using Decimal.

Comment: @TonyVitabile which data type should I use to compare **integer** values larger than Int32.MaxValue? Read it , it's from the OP

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years We all get that. But I think most of us also believe the OP is mistaken in his desire to compare integer values.

Answer (score 2):

Long(INT64) is for integers that have the maxvalue of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Long is stored in 64bit and 64 bit = 8 bytes. 1 byte can be written in a hexadecimal number with the max value of FF(F=16) per byte. So 8 bytes have the maxvalue as 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in hexadecimal or 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 in decimal.

Also, there is short(int16) which stores in 2 byte and have the maxvalue of 32767

Hope you understand

Ref:int16:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx
Ref:Int64:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.int64.maxvalue

Answer (score 2):

If your values can have up to 2 decimal points, you should use the [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type.