# Multiplying int with long result c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, int, long-integer, multiplication

Wonder why. C# .Net 3.5

```
int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
int b = 8;
long c = b * a;
Console.WriteLine(c);//<-- result is -2147483648
```

Where does this minus from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Where does this minus from?

From the integer overflow. Note that your code is equivalent to:

```
int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
int b = 8;
int tmp = b * a;
long c = tmp;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

I've separated out the multiplication from the assignment to the `long` variable to emphasize that they really are separate operations - the multiplication is performed using `Int32` arithmetic, because both operands are `Int32` - the fact that the result is assigned to an `Int64` afterwards is irrelevant.

If you want to perform the multiplication in 64-bit arithmetic, you should cast one of the operands to `long` (i.e. `Int64`):

```
int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
int b = 8;
long c = b * (long) a;
Console.WriteLine(c); // 2147483648
```

(It doesn't matter which operand you cast to `long` - the other one will be implicitly converted to `long` anyway.)

Comment: I'd been confused by the value of result which is the same as expected but with negative sign. If i would used other values it would be much clearer that is an overflow problem.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a 32 bit **signed** value type, wich means the very last bit is used to specify if the number is positive or negative.

`int` value ranges from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. This is

`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` to

`0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

in binary. Now:

`256 * 1024 * 1024` equals `268435456` or

`0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` binary.

`268435456 * 8` equals `2147483648` or

`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.

As the value is still an `int`, this loops back to the max **negative** number because, as stated, the last bit is used to specify if the number is positive or negative. So, `2147483648` is turned into `-2147483648`

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value that `int` supports is `2147483647`. The expected result `2147483648` does not fit in this type range, hence an overflow occurs causing the result to be negative.

Note that the statement `long c = b * a;` translates to the following two steps:

1. Multiple the `int` values of `b` and `a`. The `int` result is negative due to integer overflow.
2. Convert the already negative result to `long`.

Try casting to `long` before multiplying:

```
long c = b * (long) a;
```

or declare `a` be of type `long`:

```
long a = 256L * 1024L * 1024L;
```

Answer (score 1):

As was stated by others, you should have one of the operands in expression as `long` to yield `long`, but in your case all operands are `int` and therefore,  `int` is returned.

You should cast one of them to long:

```
int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
int b = 8;
long c = (long)b * a;
```

The same happens when you divide:

```
int a=1, b=2;
float c = a / b; //results in 0
```

So cast one of operands to the resulting type:

```
int a=1, b=2;
float c = (float)a / b; //results in 0.5
```

BTW, there is also C# directive for checking arithmetic overflow: `checked` keyword

```
checked
{
   int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
   int b = 8;
   long c = b * a; //this will throw System.OverflowException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cast the result to long not the operation, if one of the operands is long it works  This works fine:

```
long a = 256L * 1024L * 1024L;
int b = 8;
long c = b * a;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

as does this:

```
int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
long b = 8L;
long c = b * a;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

and this (only one of the two needs to be cast but I did both to be clear):

```
int a = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
int b = 8;
long c = (long)b * (long)a;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because b * a is already overflowed integer, before it is assigned to the long data type variable.