# C# Bug in Modulo Operator %

Tags: c#, .net, math, modulo

Solving one bug I came to some interesting discoveries.

The result of this procedure

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i4 = 4;
        Console.WriteLine("int i4 = 4;");
        Console.WriteLine("i4 % 1 = {0}", i4 % 1);

        double d4 = 4.0;
        Console.WriteLine("double d4 = 4.0;");
        Console.WriteLine("d4 % 1 = {0}", d4 % 1);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        int i64 = 64;
        double dCubeRootOf64 = Math.Pow(i64, 1.0 / 3.0);
        Console.WriteLine("int i64 = 64;");
        Console.WriteLine("double dCubeRootOf64 = Math.Pow(i64, 1.0 / 3.0) = {0}", dCubeRootOf64);
        Console.WriteLine("dCubeRootOf64 = {0}", dCubeRootOf64);
        Console.WriteLine("dCubeRootOf64 % 1 = {0} ??????????????  Why 1. ??????????", dCubeRootOf64 % 1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

is

```
int i4 = 4;
i4 % 1 = 0
double d4 = 4.0;
d4 % 1 = 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
int i64 = 64;
double dCubeRootOf64 = Math.Pow(i64, 1.0 / 3.0) = 4
dCubeRootOf64 = 4
dCubeRootOf64 % 1 = 1 ??????????????  Why 1. ??????????
```

`int 4 % 1 = 0`  -- correct

`double 4.0 % 1 = 0` -- correct

But bug is in:

**Math.Pow(64, 1.0 / 3.0) % 1 = 1**

Cube root from 64 is 4. Why is in that case `4 % 1 = 1`?

Comment: Check out Google: (64^(1/3)) mod 1

Comment: If you want to make sure that it's an integer that you're getting the modulo for, try to cast it.

Comment: You are looking for this I think

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is modulus operator not working for double in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906564/why-is-modulus-operator-not-working-for-double-in-c)

Comment: @IanMercer: No, that's not a duplicate

Comment: `Math.Pow(x, 1.0 / 3.0)` doesn't calculate the cube root, even if Pow was infinitely precise (which it isn't), because `1.0 / 3.0` is not one third - it's 0.33333333333333331.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.Pow(64, 1.0 / 3.0)` returns `3.9999999999999996`.
This gets rounded to `4` when displayed.

Taking it modulo 1 returns `0.99999999999999956`, which is similarly rounded to `1` when displayed.

You can see the true values by adding `.ToString("R")`

Comment: Thanks, Math.Pow(64, 1.0 / 3.0) returns 3.9999999999999996. - This explains everything

Answer (score 3):

`dCubeRootOf64 % 1 = 1` returns 1 instead 0; cause `Math.Pow(i64, 1.0 / 3.0)` returns `3.9999999999999996` and  `3.9999999999999996 % 1` returns `0.99999999999999956` which in turn getting rounded to 1.

Thus the result 1.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Exactly.  `4.0%1` returns `0`.

Comment: I just tried same posted code and it given 1 as o/p in 3.5 framework.

Comment: @Rahul: Exactly.  It's supposed to return `0`.