# c# : do while loop not working as supossed

Tags: c#, windows, do-while

This program should work for both the condition , atleast i think, but for some values it's not working as supposed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double num, temp = 0;
    double frac;
    int j = 1;

    num = 1034.264;            
    do
    {
        j = j * 10;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        temp = num * j;
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }
    while ((temp % 10)!=0);
}
```

For value 1034.347 , its working fine --

[working for 1034.347](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7qPp.png)

but for  value 1034.235 
[not working 1034.235](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9S0L.png)
it is going to infinite

Comment: I don't see why people have down voted this question - it is perfectly reasonable and well asked.

Comment: I agree, it's well written with expected and actual results documented (although doing that in-line would be better). Although it's tempting to close as a duplicate, my feeling that it deserves a short answer and a link to the "canonical" floating point question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is modulus operator not working for double in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906564/why-is-modulus-operator-not-working-for-double-in-c)

Answer (score 9):

C# - in order to keep up with the Joneses - has a *floating point modulus operator* `%`.

It's unlikely that the resultant binary floating point value will have all its trailing digits set to zero when represented as a decimal number, so `(temp % 10)!=0)` being `false` is a rarity.

A workaround in your case would be to work in a factor of 1000 of you values, and use an appropriate integral type.

Reference: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I don't see how the factor of a thousand will help in this case; are you assuming that the number will always have three or less non-zero digits after the decimal point?  (It seems to me that the purpose of the code is to count the number of non-zero digits after the decimal point, which implies that the number is unknown.)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing floating points numbers with equal is very dangerous, because floating point operations have an error. E.g. the number is not zero, it's 0.0[..]01 - or: near zero. I suggest comparing with a "bandwith":

```
abs(nubmer) < 0.000001.
```

Comment: A dreadful idea based on sadly very common misconceptions around what binary floating point numbers actually are: they don't have an error; it's just that the floating point set is a sparse subset of the real number set, and that sparseness is not constant so advocating a constant comparative tolerance is poor advice indeed. Do read the link in my answer.