# C# modulo is giving me the wrong asnwer?

Tags: c#, math, modulo

Hi I'm having this really weird issue with C#.

I'm trying to do a modulu operation:

```
double stepSize = 3.6;
if (180.0 % stepSize != 0) DoStuff();
```

And 180.0 % 3.6 = 0 -> ["proof"](https://www.google.dk/search?q=180+mod+3.6)

But for some reason C# returns: `3.6`

Do any one have an explanation for that

Comment: Also see: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#588014)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906564/why-is-modulus-operator-not-working-for-double-in-c/906628

Comment: `3.6` cannot be represented exactly. The closest `double` has a decimal representation of `3.6000000000000001`, which is slightly greater. As a result, there's a significant nonzero remainder. Note that `1800.0 % 36.0 == 0.0` -- small integers can be represented exactly, even in floating-point calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the floating-point arithmetics and its inability to represent all decimal numbers precisely. A simple test reveals the differences:

`decimal` type:

```
Console.WriteLine(180m % 3.6m); // 0.0
```

`float` type:

```
Console.WriteLine(180f % 3.6f); // 4.768372E-06
```

`double` type:

```
Console.WriteLine(180d % 3.6d); // 3.6
```